# Extract 1 word using regex expression

Tags: javascript

How to extract the breed of the dog from this url https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/husky/n02110185_11841.jpg ?
Considering the breed will change, what would be the regex expression to extract what's between breeds/ and the next '/'?

Comment: you don't need a regex for that - just use the `URL` parser

Answer (score 1):

`breeds\/([^\/]+)` should match your requirements.

However, regular expressions do not seem to be the right fit for this case. I recommend you parse the URL and extract the desired part from the path.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use this regex since you know it will always be this website

The key is to recognise and discard the parts before the breed name, using `\/` for the forward-slashes since they are normally delimiters for JS regexes, and then use the `(` and `)` to capture everything up to the next forward slash.

```js
const regex = /https:\/\/images\.dog\.ceo\/breeds\/([^/]+)\//


function extractBreed(s) {
  var results = regex.exec(s);
  return results[1];
}

console.log(extractBreed("https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/husky/n02110185_11841.jpg"))
console.log(extractBreed("https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/chihuahua/n02110185_11841.jpg"))
```